# валидация данных в Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Каким образом я могу задать парную валидацию в rails на данные в таблице,чтобы они больше не повторялись,пример: user_id=1,friend_id=2,и эта строка с такими(парными)значениями больше в таблицу не заносилась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала:

**Любая валидация на уникальность должна сопровождаться unique constraint'ом в БД**.
В вашем случае, составным. Пример из [документации (для миграции)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index):

```
add_index(:accounts, [:branch_id, :party_id], unique: true)
```

**Никаких исключений.** Между проверкой на отсутствие дубликатов и непосредственной записью проходит немного времени, достаточно, чтобы две записи от разных процессов смогли пролезть в базу. Такая "ситуация, где параллельные процессы могут подраться между собой и что-то сломать" называется race condition.

Валидация уникальности комбинаций полей выполняется с помощью параметра `:scope`. Для разных форм валидации  результат выглядит немножко по-разному ([документация](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, scope: :account_id                # двух полей
validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, scope: [:semester_id, :class_id] # трёх полей
validates :user_name, uniqueness: { scope: :account_id } # двух полей, sexy-синтаксис
```

---

*Вообще говоря, **unique constraint** и **unique index** это **не одно и то же**, но эту задачу любой из них успешно выполнит.*

*В чём различие? Constraint "больше", он включает в себя аналогичный индекс. Те фичи БД, что требуют именно constraint, индексом не удовлетворятся. Но мы отвлеклись.*

*Лично я обжёгся этим с PostgreSQL, используя `ON CONFLICT`, который требует именно constraint, который не может быть **частичным**, т. е. покрывать лишь некоторые строчки таблицы. Обидный момент, потребовавший переделать пол-схемы.*